# Display a png image file on a framebuffer: png-fb source

Tags: framebuffer, png

I want do display a png image on a framebuffer on an embedded Linux.
I already found the manpage of png-fb:
[man fb-png](https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=png-fb)

But I could not find a source for that. Does anybody know the source for that program?

Alternatively, is there another program to display a png image on a framebuffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [fbi (frame buffer image)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fbi) for that.

Sources are also available for [fbi improved](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/#download)

Comment: This was also helpful: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11)